# Python parse string with replace not working

Tags: python, json

I have a string to convert to json.

The string is as following:

```
s='{\\'kind\\': 1, \\'topic\\': \\'manufacturing_device\\', \\'message_type\\': 1, \\'txid\\': \\'6bcc6212a8\\', \\'name\\': \\'manufacturing\\'}'
```

I use json dumps and loads, not working

```
jStr = json.dumps(s)
loadStr = json.loads(jStr)
```

Then I need access loadStr['topic'], it gives me error "string indices must be integers'

Then I think maybe I need replace `"\\"`
Therefore, I did `s.replace('\\\'', '\"')` and didn't work either.

Any idea of what I did wrong? By the way, I use python 3.6

Comment: `s` is not JSON, and the statement is not valid Python. Please produce a [mcve]. Given that your actual code is valid, `jStr = json.dumps(s)` would produce a JSON representation of the string value in `s`, and so `json.loads(jStr)` would then decode the same string from that JSON, instead of a dictionary that you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
import ast
s='{\'kind\': 1, \'topic\': \'manufacturing_device\', \'message_type\': 1, \'txid\': \'6bcc6212a8\', \'name\': \'manufacturing\'}'

ne = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(type(ne))
print(ne['topic'])
```

Output

```
<class 'dict'>
manufacturing_device
```

Comment: Why not just do `ne=ast.literal_eval(s)` and skip the double `dumps`?

Comment: @hpaulj     import json 
import ast
s='{\'kind\': 1, \'topic\': \'manufacturing_device\', \'message_type\': 1, \'txid\': \'6bcc6212a8\', \'name\': \'manufacturing\'}'
jStr = json.dumps(s)

newtext = eval(json.dumps(jStr))

ne = ast.literal_eval(newtext)

print(type(ne)) .  returns type str

Comment: I added some clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `loadStr` is a string. so, you cannot use `getitem` on a string .

Answer (score 0):

You just pack to json a string, not a python object.

So then you trying to get value by key in this line

```
loadStr = json.loads(jStr)
```

you will get this string back.

So i think you need something like this:

```
import json
s='{"kind": 1, "topic": "manufacturing_device", "message_type": 1, "txid": "6bcc6212a8", "name": "manufacturing"}'
load_str = json.loads(s)
print(load_str['kind'])
```

By the way, when you working with python strings it's easier to use single and double quotes, in order not to escape same quotes.

```
s='{"kind": 1, "topic": "manufacturing_device", "message_type": 1, "txid": "6bcc6212a8", "name": "manufacturing"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1193]: import json
```

If `s` is a proper dictionary, `json` can create a `json` string:

```
In [1194]: s={'kind': 1, 'topic': 'manufacturing_device', 'message_type': 1, 'txid': '6bcc6212a8', 'name': 'manufacturing'}
In [1195]: s
Out[1195]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'message_type': 1,
 'name': 'manufacturing',
 'topic': 'manufacturing_device',
 'txid': '6bcc6212a8'}

In [1196]: astr = json.dumps(s)
In [1197]: astr
Out[1197]: '{"name": "manufacturing", "txid": "6bcc6212a8", "topic": "manufacturing_device", "message_type": 1, "kind": 1}'
```

Note that `s` is a dictionary; `astr` is a string.

Complete the round trip with `loads`:

```
In [1198]: s1 = json.loads(astr)
In [1199]: s1
Out[1199]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'message_type': 1,
 'name': 'manufacturing',
 'topic': 'manufacturing_device',
 'txid': '6bcc6212a8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1193]: import json
```

If `s` is a proper dictionary, `json` can create a `json` string:

```
In [1194]: s={'kind': 1, 'topic': 'manufacturing_device', 'message_type': 1, 'txid': '6bcc6212a8', 'name': 'manufacturing'}
In [1195]: s
Out[1195]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'message_type': 1,
 'name': 'manufacturing',
 'topic': 'manufacturing_device',
 'txid': '6bcc6212a8'}

In [1196]: astr = json.dumps(s)
In [1197]: astr
Out[1197]: '{"name": "manufacturing", "txid": "6bcc6212a8", "topic": "manufacturing_device", "message_type": 1, "kind": 1}'
```

Note that `s` is a dictionary; `astr` is a string.

Complete the round trip with `loads`:

```
In [1198]: s1 = json.loads(astr)
In [1199]: s1
Out[1199]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'message_type': 1,
 'name': 'manufacturing',
 'topic': 'manufacturing_device',
 'txid': '6bcc6212a8'}
```

Accessing elements of the dictionary is just standard Python:

```
In [1205]: s1['topic']
Out[1205]: 'manufacturing_device'
```

---

(edit related to my comment on the accepted answer)

This expression creates a string:

```
In [1214]: s='{\'kind\': 1, \'topic\': \'manufacturing_device\', \'message_type\': 1, \'txid\': \'6bcc6212a8\', \'name\': \'manufacturing\'}'
In [1215]: s
Out[1215]: "{'kind': 1, 'topic': 'manufacturing_device', 'message_type': 1, 'txid': '6bcc6212a8', 'name': 'manufacturing'}"
```

It's a valid Python expression, which `literal_eval` can evaluate, and create a dictionary:

```
In [1216]: ne = ast.literal_eval(s)
In [1217]: ne
Out[1217]: 
{'kind': 1,
 'message_type': 1,
 'name': 'manufacturing',
 'topic': 'manufacturing_device',
 'txid': '6bcc6212a8'}
```

There's no need to wrap it in one or more `json.dumps` and then unwrap with `loads` or `eval`.